# Exclude sticky posts from query

Tags: query, sticky-post

I used `orderby=date` and `orderby=comment_count` to show my recent post and popular post, but sticky post is always there on the top.

How can exclude sticky posts?

Answer (score 0):

You should also use `ignore_sticky_posts=1` (it's default value is 0, so sticky posts aren't ignored and returned at top of posts list).

More on pagination parameters: http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query#Pagination_Parameters